# How to use pagination on costum post type

Tags: pagination

i made a costum post type use plugin Costum post type UI

and i tried to display i on homepage / index

code

```
<?php args1 = array( 'post_type' => 'app', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );$the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
    <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
echo "no post found"; }?>
```

so , how to display the pagination ??

**thank's**

*sory my bad english

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; $args = array( 'post_type'=>'post', // Your post type name
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'paged' => $paged,); $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); // YOUR CODE
endwhile;
$total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
if ($total_pages > 1){
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
        'next_text'    => __('next »'),
    ));
}} wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?